# Checkbox stateSave in Datatables Table disappears after Cache Refresh (all other stateSaves working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

Note: Among the obvious (DataTables, jQuery) I am using..

- `jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.9/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css`
- `jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.9/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js`
- `select/1.2.5/css/select.dataTables.min.css`
- `select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js`

And using a live API call to populate my tables.

As described in the title, all other saveStates seem to be functioning as they should in `localStorage` (paging, ordering, etc), after a hard refresh on my datatable.

With checkboxes, I've gotten them to remain in a semi-saved state, meaning if I refresh they stay, but after a cache refresh (`ctrl+f5`), they are gone.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the `stateSaveCallback` and `stateLoadCallback`.. and there are also some things such as `StateLoaded`, `StateLoadParams`, `StateSaveParams` in the dataTables [stateSave documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave).

Here is my Datatable Initalization at the bottom of my page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){  
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'columnDefs': [
         {
            'targets': 0,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            'checkboxes': {
               'selectRow': true
            }
         }
      ],
      'select': {
            style:    'multi+shift',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
      'order': [[1, 'asc']],
      'paging': false,
      'stateSave': true,
      'stateSaveCallback': function(settings,data) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data) )
    },
      'stateLoadCallback': function(settings) {
      return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance ) )
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

The PHP and HTML seem to be working and populating fine, so I don't think posting the full script is necessary, but here is the checkbox portion and a glance

```
// getting the variables from the API call

$results .= "<tr><td>$rowCount</td><td><a href=\"$largepic\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"$largepic\" style=\"width:225px;height:auto;\"></a> . . . . .
```

I am using is the [gyroscope datatables checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in, which requires a custom id (hence `$rowCount` which is just an `$i++` increment a `for each` loop.

But as stated, stateSave is working fine for all other elements. Checkboxes and other inputs are apparently a special breed?

And honestly I tried many things, but most either worked strangely or broke the script. The initialization above is actually the best I could get it. I would post a demo but because it's an API initialization I can't do so.

Anyone, please, have been through this or have an idea of what I can do?
This seems to be a common problem, with stateSaving through elements like this. Checkboxes, drop-downs. I'm assuming the checkboxes need to be held in `localStorage` properly and once again retrieved, but a solution is hard to sculpt for me and there is little information that I've found that directly addresses this.

The Gyrocode DataTables CheckBox plug-in is actually pretty well documented, and illustrates examples of [stateSave](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/basic/state-saving/) and [keepConditions](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-save-and-restore-table-state-using-unique-url/) on their site, but all has fallen short thus far. It probably has something to do with how I am retrieving the data and needing a special condition to retrieve it. That is my best guess thus far.

Looking through the gyroscope examples, I see a method he is using to capture the checkbox data in datatables

```
var rows_selected = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();

      // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
      $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
         // Create a hidden element
         $(form).append(
             $('<input>')
                .attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', 'id[]')
                .val(rowId)
         );
      });
```

So this illustrates getting the checkbox data through datatables -- in this example through a form submit.

What am I missing that will persist the checkboxes like the other elements alongside it?

I am using the latest dataTables as of 4/02/2018, `v1.10.16`.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug corrected in the [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in in version `1.10.11` that prevented proper state saving on subsequent page reloads, see [this issue #64](https://github.com/gyrocode/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/issues/64).

Use the [latest release](https://github.com/gyrocode/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/releases/latest) and the problem with state saving should go away.